# When mirroring my Macbook Pro with an ultra-wide external display, can the resolution be set to the external's native resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

To emphasize again, this question is about *mirroring*. I'm looking at buying a 3440x1440 (or higher) resolution monitor, and I'd like to use it as the *only* display with my MBP while keeping the MBP open. From my research, it doesn't seem possible to do this. The workaround I found, was to mirror the displays. So, if I do that, will the resolution match the external display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When mirroring, you can choose which display to "optimize" for.

[image]